# Set Grid item columns with an object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to set  columns using an object. Something like this:

```
const obj = { item1: { xs: 12, lg: 8, xl: 9, xxl: 7 }, item2: { xs: 12, lg: 4, xl: 3, xxl: 5 } };
<Grid item columns={obj.item1}></Grid>
<Grid item columns={obj.item2}></Grid>
```

I think the 'columns' prop is only usable with the  to set the grid composition. In the above code I've used 'columns' because I don't know what to use.

Is there a way to do it?